# Public (or not?) event in Thailand - Who owns copyright of pictures?

Tags: copyright

I don't know if it could help in the question, but I will state some informations about me:

Nationality = Italian
Residence = Germany

A week ago I was in Thailand and took some photos of performers during a dinner with show. It was not possible for me to make them sign any paper about copyrights etc.

My question is: was the performance "public" (we were after all in a restaurant, which I believe was a private place) and if so who owns the copyrights? What can I cannot do with those pictures and which law should I obey to (Thai, Italian, German)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think this question fits better at http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Under "copyright law" the copyright ownership *always* goes to the photographer (with exceptions, like if the photographer is acting as an employee performing work duties, etc), and copyright law is pretty much compatible in almost every country of the world.  However, there are other laws, other than copyright, which could affect your ability to shoot in this location, and for that I agree with the recommendation to take your questions elsewhere.  Asking an actual lawyer is probably preferable, but law.stackexchange may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Thailand law specifically, and you should probably ask a lawyer familiar with the law there and in your own country of residence about it, but generally speaking, unless you are doing work for hire, the copyright holder is the one making artistic decisions about the image in much of the world, in this case, the photographer.

That may not mean that you have a right to use the images though.  There are many rights other than copyright that may impact the contents of a picture.  Some jurisdictions have rights for the use of someone's likeness and their may be rules about your actual right to have made an image in the first place that could still impact you.

What copyright does do for you is that it prevents someone else from using your images without your permission.  It may not be all that is necessary to make sure that you have a right to use the same images though.

Comment: Even if I will need further investigation on the law website, I think this answer can be taken as the correct one, since it clarified to me a couple of things